# If there's $c > 0$ such that $a_{n+1} - a_n > c$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for my calculus exam, and I'm having trouble understanding the solution of this exercise:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence.
> If there's $c > 0$ such that $a_{n+1} - a_n > c$ for every n then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$

Here is the proof:

> We'll prove in induction that for every natural n exists $a_n\geq a_1 + (n-1)c$.
>
> For $n=1$ then $a_1=a_1+(1-1)c$.
>
> We'll prove it for some n, meaning: $a_n\geq a_1+(n-1)$: Since we're given that $a_{n+1} -a_n > c$ then $a_{n+1}>a_n+c$. Therefore: $a_{n+1}>a_n+c \geq (a_1 + (n-1)c)+c=a_1+nc=a_1+((n+1)-1)c$, therefore the induction step is complete.
>
> Now, $a_1 + (n-1)c=a_1-c+nc=n(\frac{a_1-c}{n} + c)$, from limits arithmetic: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n(\frac{a_1-c}{n} + c))=c$, and from the rule "positive * infinity": $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_1+(n-1)c)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n(\frac{a_1-c}{n} + c)) = \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$.

I'm having trouble understanding the induction assumption, how and where did "$a_1+(n−1)c$" come from? I understand what he's done in most of the proof from there, but getting to $(n-1)c$ is not obvious to me, how did he get to that?

Thank you for clarifying it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $a_{n+1}-a_n\ge c$ implies that

- $a_2 \ge a_1+c$
- $a_3 \ge a_2+c\ge a_1+2c$
- $a_4 \ge a_3+c\ge a_1+3c$
- $\ldots$
- $a_{n} \ge a_{n-1}+c\ge a_1+(n-1)c$

that is $a_{n} \ge a_1+(n-1)c$ which is assumed in the inductive step.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to see that is to observe the following statement:
$$a_n-a_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k -a_{k-1}$$
Thus summation is called telescopic sum.

Then you get:
$$a_n-a_0 \geq  \sum_{k=1}^n c = nc$$
Which gives us:
$$a_n \geq a_0 + nc \to \infty$$
Your version is the same but you come from $a_1$ instead of $a_0$. I’m pretty confident you’ll see it is not different!